# Как получить тип элемента абсолютно любой коллекции (IEnumerable) C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим, у меня есть объект массива или коллекции. Существует ли универсальный способ извлечь у них тип элемента? Вроде как все они реализуют IEnumerable и ICollection.

Comment: Приведите больше информации, как вы используете эти коллекции.

Comment: Тут есть еще одно уточнение, где именно нужно это получить/узнать, внутри объекта списка, внутри элемента, или снаружи списка.

Comment: Задача уже решена, я получил тип массива/коллекции и через GetInterface("IEnumerable`1").GetGenericParameters()[0] получил нужный тип.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, вам нужны обобщённые методы. Пример:

```
static void Main()
{
    var arr = new string[] { "a" };
    var list = new List<int> { 1 };

    Method(arr); // System.String
    Method(list); // System.Int32
}

static void Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Задача уже решена, я получил тип массива/коллекции и через GetInterface("IEnumerable`1").GetGenericParameters()[0] получил нужный тип.

Comment: Я пишу нестандартную связку между ЯП'ами, и мне нужна была абсолютная динамика.

Comment: @Antinet - напишите полноценный ответ (и примите его)

Answer (score 0):

Данным способом можно получить тип элемента любой коллекции.

```
static void Main()
{
    var arr = new string[] { "a" };
    var list = new List<int> { 1 };

    GetElementType(arr); // System.String
    GetElementType(list); // System.Int32
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

static void GetElementType(IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumerable.GetType().GetInterface("IEnumerable`1").GetGenericArguments()[0]);
}
```